# how to use postgresql condition with solr sunspot rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot-solr

I have a list of posts with status which means

```
status 1 - active
status 0 - removed
status 2 - pending
```

My solr seearch in index everything so if I search It is showing all the posts irrespective of the status code. I need only posts with `status 1`

I tried something like this

```
@search = Post.where(status: 1).search do
      fulltext params[:search] do
        minimum_match 1
      end
      paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 15
    end
    @posts = @search.results
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render nothing: true }
      format.html
    end
```

How can I do this. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@search.results`, you can use `@search.result_ids` in an ActiveRecord `where` clause.

```
@posts = Post.where(:id => @search.result_ids).where(status: 1)
```

This actually isn't a great option, because if your search is including results that don't have the status you want, then the pagination isn't going to match up nicely with your database.

Better to index the `status` field in your model's `searchable` block, and instruct Solr to filter on that column in your search.

```
class Post
  searchable do
    # other fields...
    integer :status
  end
end

@search = Post.search do
  # other search options
  with :status, 1
end

@posts = @search.results
```

Comment: I have a admin panel to change the status to 1. But after changing I need to reindex to get the result. Is there any way to automatically index it